# jQuery: Sliding via anchorlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor, sliding

I loaded this jQuery-snippet for sliding a page via anchorLinks.

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/

In my case I have a fixed block (position:fixed) on the top of the page. Due to that I need a delta value for sliding down. If I don't use such a delta value the page is sliding to deep so that my anchorLink is hidden by the fixed block.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this issue?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a solution by editing this line:

```
 window.location.hash = elementClick
```

Changing the duration value helps to slide to right position. But then the window "jumps" the offset-value at the end of the sliding.

**Solution**: I fixed the problem by removing line:

```
 window.location.hash = elementClick
```

Answer (score 0):

The original Plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

**Modified**:

```
jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100,
          offset: 0
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination+settings.offset}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

Note that I've just added an `offset` option. So if your fixed div has a height of 60px then just call it with `$('#whatever').anchorAnimate({offset: 60});`

Comment: Thanks!!!! I tried this by adding a static value, e.g. 60px. But I think that "window.location.hash = elementClick" is the problem.

Comment: Your change doesn't fix the problem. :-(